# Use ng-repeat index as class name?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use the $index of ng-repeat in the class name?

Example:

```
ng-class="{'hand-' + $index: true}"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
ng-class="['hand-' + $index]"
```

Additionally, you can use the class attribute to interpolate the class value

```
class="hand-{{$index}}"
```

Comment: Thank you...is there a favorit way?

Comment: yes, I prefer the class attribute solution as it is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use within html class:

```
class="list-{{$index}}"
```

for  Angular use:

```
ng-class="['hand-' + $index]"
```